# Is there an efficient way to show and remove specific buttons after you click on them and play audio?

Tags: javascript, html, button, interactive, flowchart

I am making a website with Javascript on which you can press a button to play an audio file. When the audio ends, it shows two new buttons and removes the first one. I'm trying to make an interactive audio story, that let's users choose at multiple points in the story. [like this flowchart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UoHMz.png)

I already tried to make a button with an id and `onclick()= play()`. 
in javascript i use `getElementById` to do style.display and style.visibility.

This kind of works, but it's not efficient as i need to make 50+ buttons.

HTML

```
<a class="btn btn-light" id="introbutton" onclick="playstart()" role="button">start</a>

<audio id="introaudio" src="audio/bel.WAV" ></audio>
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
function playstart(){
   var introaudio = document.getElementById("introaudio");
   introaudio.play();
}
introaudio.onended = function() {
   document.getElementById("introbutton").style.display = "none";

   document.getElementById("button2A").style.visibility = "visible";
   document.getElementById("button2B").style.visibility = "visible";
};
```

i was hoping there would be some solution where i can just give my filenames a number and A/B name. example: audio2A.mp3. And when you would choose button 2A it would automatically choose that file and show two buttons related to that choice.

Comment: I'm sure one of the two new buttons is supposed to start the next audio file but what's the purpose of the second button?

Comment: Yes! The other button needs to play another audio file

Comment: I'm sorry but I still didn't get it. At startup there's just one button - which starts playback. If playback is finished this button should vanish and two new buttons should appear. What exactly should these two buttons trigger? And lastly - what should happen if playback finished? Again two new buttons which should do the same as the previous two?

Comment: Yes indeed. after the first button is pushed, it plays an audio file. After the playback is finished the button disappears and two new ones appear. They have the same function: playing audio. Just another audiofile for each button.